# How update web reference from VS 2008 command line?

Tags: visual-studio

We have web references in our VS 2008 solution. We don't check in generated files. I need to update the generated files on our cruise control server -- so I need a command line method to update the web references.  Is there a way to force devenv to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no command you can pass to Visual Studio from the command line to do this. What you can do though is use the wsdl.exe tool to generate the web references yourself.  Under the hood, Visual Studio uses the same API as wsdl.exe to generate the references so there shouldn't be a functional difference between the two pieces of generated code (provided you give wsdl the right parameters)

WSDL.exe

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx

Comment: So is there a way to capture the params that devenv hands off to wsdl.exe?

Comment: @Dave C, unfortunately no because it actually doesn't even use wsdl.exe.  They both use the same API under the hood.  The parameters are pretty straight forward though.  Mainly namespace for code and the URL of the web service.