# update web reference through commandline

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2008, asmx

Is there a way to update web reference in a Visual Studio 2008 project through command line?
I have a test code that reference to a web service.I want to run this against different servers and trying to write a script for this.

Comment: duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229681/how-update-web-reference-from-vs-2008-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly the duplication of the following:

[How update web reference from VS 2008 command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229681/how-update-web-reference-from-vs-2008-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with the following :

### WDSLBuildParameters.xml

```
<wsdlParameters xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webReference/">
  <nologo>true</nologo>
  <parsableerrors>true</parsableerrors>
  <sharetypes>true</sharetypes>
  <webReferenceOptions>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <codeGenerationOptions>properties newAsync</codeGenerationOptions>
    <style>client</style>
  </webReferenceOptions>
</wsdlParameters>
```

### UpdateWebReferences.bat

```
>> PSUDOCODE here... Executed from the .\Web References\yourproxyclass folder...

wsdl.exe /n:yournamespace.yourproxyclass /parameters:"WDSLBuildParameters.xml" /out:"Reference.cs" "http://yourserviceendpoint"

Disco.exe "yourserviceendpoint:port"

SvcUtil.exe /n:"*,proxyclass" "http://yourserviceendpoint:port"

REM Copy and rename files...

COPY /y Reference.cs ..\
COPY /y results.discomap Reference.map
```

This generates everything except the .datasource files, but in my case I don't need them updated so I am happy with the solution.